# Constrained Triangulation of a Convex Polytope

Tags: co.combinatorics

Hi,

I am looking for an algorithm that can do a constrained triangulation of a convex polytope (nDimensional). The constraint is that it should contain certain n-1Dimensional simplicies. Can someone recommend a paper, or at least a paper that does this in an unconstrained way? I am not interested in any properties of the triangulation (Delaunay - too complicated for my problem) and no points should be inserted.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Once you have pre-specified some simplices $S$ that must be included in your triangulation
of the convex polytope $P$, what remains is the problem of triangulating a nonconvex region:
$P \setminus S$.
There are nonconvex polyhedra (in dimension 3) that cannot be triangulated.
I believe one could make such an example from the [Schönhardt polyhedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhardt_polyhedron),
by insisting on the inclusion of three tetrahedra ($S$) external to that polyhedron as 
part of a triangulation of the convex hull ($P$) of two twisted triangles in parallel planes,
so that $P \setminus S$ is the un-tetrahedralizable Schönhardt polyhedron
(see below).
And it is an NP-complete problem to decide if a given nonconvex polyhedron can be triangulated,
a 1992 result of Ruppert and Seidel.

[image]
           <sub>([Image from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhardt_polyhedron))</sub>

If you want to nevertheless hope that your region can be triangulated, you might explore
[geometric bistellar flips](http://www.voronoi.com/wiki/index.php?title=Bistellar_flips) to underlie an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer! What is the situation like if I have a Ndim polytope that I want to triangulate and my constraint is that it that its N-simplicies should contain certain N-1-simplicies? For example, in 3D, I want the triangulation of the polyhedron to contain certain triangles.

Comment: I believe the situation is essentially the same as in my answer: Sometimes the triangulation cannot be completed; it is NP-complete to determine if the triangulation can be completed; and likely bistellar flips might lead to a reasonable algorithm.